calculating count and sum with a condition and on multiple category
This is my data.
irisData<-as.data.table(iris)
bins<-seq(4, length.out = 9, by = 0.5);
aggtable <- data.table(bin1 = bins[-length(bins)], bin2 = bins[-1])

I would like to create a count and sum of the Sepal.Length categorized by a defined class intervals which is bins and by Species.
This is the output which I need. first one is a count and bottom is a sum on Sepal.Length.

This question is an extension of my previous question.
I am trying to edit this code:
this does the work but only totals, categorization by Species is required as in the table above.
irisData[aggtable,on = .( Sepal.Length >= bin1, Sepal.Length < bin2 ) , .(Count= .N) , .EACHI]
irisData[aggtable,on = .( Sepal.Length >= bin1, Sepal.Length < bin2 ) , .(Sepal.Length.sum = sum(Sepal.Length)) , .EACHI]

A few things.
Appreciate if it can be done using data.table package.
I would like to see zeros if no value in the bins.

Following the non-equi join approach of the previous question, which allows for any bin specification, you can create this little helper function
f <- \(a,x) {
  setNames(
    data.table(s=x, t=x)[a, on=.(s >= bin1, s < bin2), .(ct=.N, xsum = nafill(sum(t),fill = 0)), .EACHI],
    c("bin1", "bin2", "Count", "Sepal.Length")
  )
}

Now, if you run this function, by Species, as follows:
result = irisData[, f(aggtable, Sepal.Length), by=Species]

You will get the following:
       Species  bin1  bin2 Count Sepal.Length
        <fctr> <num> <num> <int>        <num>
 1:     setosa   4.0   4.5     4         17.5
 2:     setosa   4.5   5.0    16         75.9
 3:     setosa   5.0   5.5    25        128.7
 4:     setosa   5.5   6.0     5         28.2
 5:     setosa   6.0   6.5     0          0.0
 6:     setosa   6.5   7.0     0          0.0
 7:     setosa   7.0   7.5     0          0.0
 8:     setosa   7.5   8.0     0          0.0
 9: versicolor   4.0   4.5     0          0.0
10: versicolor   4.5   5.0     1          4.9
11: versicolor   5.0   5.5     5         25.7
12: versicolor   5.5   6.0    20        113.2
13: versicolor   6.0   6.5    15         92.5
14: versicolor   6.5   7.0     8         53.5
15: versicolor   7.0   7.5     1          7.0
16: versicolor   7.5   8.0     0          0.0
17:  virginica   4.0   4.5     0          0.0
18:  virginica   4.5   5.0     1          4.9
19:  virginica   5.0   5.5     0          0.0
20:  virginica   5.5   6.0     6         34.6
21:  virginica   6.0   6.5    17        106.4
22:  virginica   6.5   7.0    14         93.8
23:  virginica   7.0   7.5     6         43.4
24:  virginica   7.5   8.0     6         46.3
       Species  bin1  bin2 Count Sepal.Length

If you want separate wide frames for each of your "outcomes" (Count and Sepal.Length), you can do this:
lapply(c("Count", "Sepal.Length"), \(o) dcast(result, bin1+bin2~Species, value.var=o)) 

Which will give you the following:
[[1]]
Key: <bin1, bin2>
    bin1  bin2 setosa versicolor virginica
   <num> <num>  <int>      <int>     <int>
1:   4.0   4.5      4          0         0
2:   4.5   5.0     16          1         1
3:   5.0   5.5     25          5         0
4:   5.5   6.0      5         20         6
5:   6.0   6.5      0         15        17
6:   6.5   7.0      0          8        14
7:   7.0   7.5      0          1         6
8:   7.5   8.0      0          0         6

[[2]]
Key: <bin1, bin2>
    bin1  bin2 setosa versicolor virginica
   <num> <num>  <num>      <num>     <num>
1:   4.0   4.5   17.5        0.0       0.0
2:   4.5   5.0   75.9        4.9       4.9
3:   5.0   5.5  128.7       25.7       0.0
4:   5.5   6.0   28.2      113.2      34.6
5:   6.0   6.5    0.0       92.5     106.4
6:   6.5   7.0    0.0       53.5      93.8
7:   7.0   7.5    0.0        7.0      43.4
8:   7.5   8.0    0.0        0.0      46.3


Using dcast after aggregating:
dcast(
  irisData[
    ,.(stat = c("count", "sum"), val = c(.N, sum(Sepal.Length))),
    .(bin1 = findInterval(Sepal.Length, bins), Species)
  ][,`:=`(bin1 = bins[bin1], bin2 = bins[bin1 + 1])],
  bin1 + bin2 ~ Species + stat, value.var = "val", fill = 0
)
#> Key: <bin1, bin2>
#>     bin1  bin2 setosa_count setosa_sum versicolor_count versicolor_sum virginica_count virginica_sum
#>    <num> <num>        <num>      <num>            <num>          <num>           <num>         <num>
#> 1:   4.0   4.5            4       17.5                0            0.0               0           0.0
#> 2:   4.5   5.0           16       75.9                1            4.9               1           4.9
#> 3:   5.0   5.5           25      128.7                5           25.7               0           0.0
#> 4:   5.5   6.0            5       28.2               20          113.2               6          34.6
#> 5:   6.0   6.5            0        0.0               15           92.5              17         106.4
#> 6:   6.5   7.0            0        0.0                8           53.5              14          93.8
#> 7:   7.0   7.5            0        0.0                1            7.0               6          43.4
#> 8:   7.5   8.0            0        0.0                0            0.0               6          46.3

